# Unable to create C++ Project correctly in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I try to create `win32` C++ project it's giving me the following error:

```
Unable to read the file. project cannot be loaded. Root element is missing
```

Here is a screen shot. I had to reinstall the studio:

[image]

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\...\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` referenced in the error message exist? Can you open it in Notepad?

Comment: Try to delete `bin` and `obj` folders

Comment: there is nothing in the folder

Comment: Have you seen Microsoft's forums and MSDN? Perhaps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cba01040-067e-4ac3-ba4c-a8a14ba3c45d/unable-to-read-the-project-file link will be usefull. Mu suggestion is to ask the same question on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=msbuild

Comment: its Asking that unable to find the project file name.vcxproj @dxiv

Comment: The real error is the missing `.props` file, which is what causes the `.vcxproj` to fail loading.

Answer (score 1):

The `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` is missing, as the OP clarified in a comment. This would suggest that the VS (re)installation did not complete successfully.

For a quick try, you could create the missing file yourself in `Notepad` with the following contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

</Project>
```

Chances are, however, that there may be more issues with the VS installation than just this missing file.